# Why start at C drive in modern computing?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the B: drive in Windows and why does the hard drive default to C?](https://superuser.com/questions/42553/what-happened-to-the-b-drive-in-windows-and-why-does-the-hard-drive-default-to-c)
>   [Can I install Windows 7 in A:\ or B:\ partition names?](https://superuser.com/questions/330865/can-i-install-windows-7-in-a-or-b-partition-names)

This question is similar to this one: [What happened to the B: drive in Windows and why does the hard drive default to C?](https://superuser.com/questions/42553/what-happened-to-the-b-drive-in-windows-and-why-does-the-hard-drive-default-to-c) but a bit different.

I understand why C drive uses that letter back in the days of Floppy Disk. But floppy disk are no longer used. So why is it in a brand new computer the hard drive is still labeled as C drive vs starting at A and then working down.

Comment: This should be closed as between those two post answer this. I saw this first post but missed the other one. Thanks =>

Comment: Also directly related - [What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](http://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've seen in the other question, lots of computers in the early days had two floppy drives, so they were A: and B:.

It became an industry standard, and there's no real reason to change it.  Everyone is used to the C: drive being the main drive, and there is still a lot of software out there that depends on it.

Comment: I did not think about the software aspect and drive letters. Thanks =>

Comment: Many computer *only* had 1 floppy drive.  Having 2 floppy drives was a luxury for a while.  Hard drives didnt become standard till much later.

Comment: @Keltari, yep, I started on Apple II+s with just one big drive.  And it was many years later until two floppy drives was standard.